# Redirect from a file in Laravel 8

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-blade, qr-code, laravel-8

have the following problem, and is that I need to redirect from a link which is created by me with 6 random characters to make a shortener to a file. The problem is that when I try to access the file I get the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/proyect/public/assets/PDFs/file.pdf` but I do not need this url, but the following, which would be from `C://.`

My doubt is, how could I do this? Since I can't find anything that can solve it and I have been trying for days to find the problem and trying in other ways, even with:

```
Storage::disk('local')->get($qr->document)
```

The blade code is as follows:

```
 <a class="button shortlink" href="{{ route('shorten.linkDocument', $qr->code) }}" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
    {{ route('shorten.linkDocument', $qr->code) }} </a> <br>.
```

Where it says `$qr->code` are the 6 random characters generated to act as a shortener and redirector. The route to `shorten.linkDocument` is found in Web, and is as follows:

```
Route::get('Pdf/{code}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QrController@shortenLinkDocument')->name('shorten.linkDocument');
```

The method referenced by the controller is as follows:

```
    public function shortenLinkDocument($code).
{
    $find = Qr::where('code', $code)->first();

    return redirect($find->document);
}
```

PS: In `$qr->document` the absolute path from `C://` is stored.

I hope for your help and thank you very much if you have read everything.

Comment: Place files you want publicly available inside your `public` folder.

Comment: They are linked to public througth the Storage class.